# In Ubuntu 16.10, multitouch on Apple Magic Mouse 2 is useless

Tags: python, 16.10, multi-touch, apple, magic-mouse

I have a new Magic Mouse 2 used in Ubuntu 16.10 through bluetooth. However, click is ok, but multitouch is useless. I search online, find a solution based on Python-pymt. This pymt package is only used in Ubuntu 14.04, and relevant website is 404. 
Could anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this same thing (except old mouse on new computer), and discovered on the PyMT page this: "PyMT is now deprecated in favor of Kivy"

So, the installation procedure for Kivy is this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
```

I don't know how (or why!) the "preferred" way to control a multitouch device became using a multi-platform application development tool, or how to even use it to accomplish the task at hand. That's very much against everything that's right, good and pure about Linux, but that is a discussion for another place and time.

What I know is that the people who used to maintain PyMT say that they no longer do so and Kivy is what they recommend.